# Broken recovery, missing system e739

Tags: recovery-mode, unbricking

e739 
I had used the twrp recovery.img from e730 and it worked fine, flashed cm7, worked great.
Then i saw that someone had made twrp for e739. I was going to flash that as well as an unofficial cm10 rom. I wiped system, then i thought i should probs do the recovery first, so i did, rebooted into recovery, and now, along with 4 tiny screens and pink everything, I can't flash anything. It would seem the recovery doesn't work. How can I fix this?

EDIT: I am getting an error saying it can't open the zip file. The file is fine, i did MD5 check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can access an adb shell, you can flash a recovery.

If you open the recovery zip up and go to META-INF/com/google/android/ you will find 2 files, you want "updater-script". Open this up with a text editor, and look for something that says dd followed by recovery.img. In that line near the end there should be something like "of=/dev/block/mtdblocknumbersnstuff"

copy that line. From here on I will refer to that as "of=x"

now go back to the zip folder and extract recovery.img to somewhere convienient. Connect your phone to the computer and boot into recovery, then run

```
adb push /path/to/recovery.img /data/recovery.img
adb shell
#cd data
#ls
```

Here it can output a bunch of stuff or nothing, but you are looking for "recovery.img" If you see it, good job, continue. If not, start over from the "adb push" command.

```
dd if=recovery.img of=x
```

From there reboot back into recovery and you should see the recovery you just flashed.